# CISC vs MIPS do the same job example

Tags: assembly, compare, mips

I'm studying advanced computer architecture, i am really not understand about MIPS and CISC.
Does anyone have a small code in both way CISC and MIPS do the same simple job, or a simple function but run in both CISC and MIPS to compare them?
thank you very much

Comment: By "MIPS" I assume you mean "RISC".

Comment: (Your best bet would be to search the literature from the early 1980s for articles on this topic.)

Comment: take x86 vs mips for example, and add two numbers that are in ram, and put the result in ram...

Comment: just give me an example please

Comment: Example to add a number in ram to another number in ram (operands are destination, source): CISC: | load register, ram1 | addtomemory ram2, register | versus RISC: | load register1, ram1 | load register2, ram2 | add register2, register1 | store ram2, register2 | .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about processor design theory, not a practical programming question. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com. Note also that SO is not a "Please solve my problem for me" site; it's a "I started solving this problem but ran into difficulty." Third, why not ask your instructor?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to look at code for difference processors you can use this: http://ellcc.org/blog/?page_id=340
You can enter code you'd like to see compiled, choose a target, and then hit "Compile Source Code" to see the results.